# Is it possible to dynamically change resources from XML-file?

Tags: android, xml, resources

I want to easily be able to change the UI apperance (colors & logo) of an app and thought to ask if someone has any suggestions on how best to do it.

What I want is simply to replace an XML-file in the project before compiling it and having the resources (i.e. the color values in colors.xml) set to the values of the XML.
The only problem seems to be that there is no way to change resources at runtime(?)

Is there any way of changing the resources automatically at authortime?

The whole point of simply replacing the XML file for different UI apperances is to save time and minimize the amount of editing different parts of the code.

Comment: If you set your original application up as a library project. Then create a new project and use this library, the new projects XML files will overwrite anything in the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then I think all you want is Theming for your application, I do not know whether you can change Resources in runtime or not, but you can definitely have separate themes for each of your UI component, which you can apply dynamically.

A good guide on Theming can be found here:

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/

Try the theming and see if it works for you or not.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. Now I just replace an xml-file in the project and all color values etc are read from there. Still, it would have been nice being able to change an actual R.drawable.x content at runtime from xml (base64) info, but it doesnt seem possible. So I'll just have to replace the icon drawable manually. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

At run time u can change the XML resource file using setcontentview(R.layout.yourfilename). You can put this line of code at any part of your execution in the project code.

Comment: This won't change resource XML, only runtime object parameters are changed.